# Drag n Drop with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

So, I've got a uni project to do and we gotta do a drag and drop with some sort of rectangle in JavaFX. And so, it works, but when the drop is done, it does not end, it just stays like I didn't drop. Although, my code is pretty short, here it is, thank's for your help ^^.

That's the code of the destination

```java
    this.setOnDragOver(event ->
    {
    if(event.getGestureSource() != this && event.getDragboard().hasContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT))
            {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        this.setOnDragDropped(event ->
        {
            for(StepIG e : world)
            {
                // If the StepIG is the one we need to drag
                if(event.getDragboard().getContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT).equals(e.getId()) && event.getTransferMode().equals(TransferMode.MOVE))
                {
                    e.reSetPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY();
                    world.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            event.setDropCompleted(true);
            event.consume();
        });
this.setOnDragDone(event -> System.out.println("smthing"));
```

and the code of the source :

```java
        this.setOnDragDetected(event ->
        {
            Dragboard dragboard = this.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent ccontent = new ClipboardContent();
            ccontent.putString(this.getEtape().getId());
            dragboard.setContent(ccontent);
            event.consume();
        });
```

PS : I forgot to mention that I isolated the problem to the function "setOnDragOver()"

Comment: Try to create a [mre] that reproduces the problem from scratch, then [edit] your question to add said example. It's hard, for me at least, to see the whole picture from the snippets you provided.

Comment: Oh yeah sure, I forgot that it was specific sorry ^^' I tried to do a minimal example now,

The destination tries to locate the id associated to the source, that's the hardest part of the code in this example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, after a few hours of research I found the answer, my jfx version couldn't handle DnD... I guess... So I had to add a VM argument : -Djdk.gtk.version=2, plus, if you want to add an image or whatever anything else, add this VM argument : -Dprism.forceGPU=true

Comment: Ah, yes. I assume you're using Linux then? Somewhere around JavaFX 9 they updated to use GTK 3 by default but there were apparently some incompatible changes that they've slowly been working to resolve, as I understand it. If you aren't already, does using the latest version of JavaFX (version 16) remove the problem?

Comment: Yep, I am. We're using JavaFX 11 for our project so that's why, and I don't think I can change the version else they will have compatibility problems (as they're used to use JavaFX 11) but thank's a lot for the explanations though !